# JavaScript: не добавляется класс getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript

Фиксированный класс:

```
.fixed-container {
            background-color: #242a35;
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
        }
```

Блок к которому необходимо добавить фиксированный класс:

```
<div class="wrapper-container">
            
        </div>
```

Код JavaScript:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    var wrapperContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper-container');
    var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    if (scrollTop > 50) {
     wrapperContainer.classList.add('fixed-container');
    }
   }
```

Ошибка:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, что не так сделал?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что в var wrapperContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper-container') у Вас не один элемент, а коллекция. Если у Вас это один такой элемент, напишите:

```
var wrapperContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper-container')[0]
```